# Icons in PyQt application not showing up

Tags: qt, pyqt, icons

I'm having a hard time making the icons from my application visible when the it runs. I've tried everything I could search, and still I don't know what could be wrong. My current dir looks like:

```
myapp/
├─ main.py
├─ icons_rc.py
├─ ui_window.py
├─ window.ui
├─ icons.qrc
├─ icons/
│  ├─ icon1.png
|  ├─ ...
|  ├─ iconN.png
```

The `icons_rc.py` file was generated with the command `pyrcc5 icons.qrc -o icons_rc.py` and it's imported to both the `main.py` and `ui_window.py`.

The `icons.qrc` file was generated in QtDesigner as the following:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>icons/icon1.png</file>
    ...
    <file>icons/iconN.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I've tried generating the `.qrc` file again, putting it inside the `icons` folder, changing the prefix of the file, and looked extensively into tutorials on how to do it step-by-step and still I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The physical files don't matter if you're using a resource files (since they are stored inside it), so you're probably not using the correct paths in the UI, which is automatically "linked" when you select "Choose Resource" in the icon field of the button in Designer: maybe you selected "Choose File", which might not work properly if the program or interpreter is run from another path. Note that if you want to use resources from code, you must use the `:/path/file` syntax (note the colon prefix).

Comment: @musicamante I'm using the resources file; here's an example of how I normally call an Icon object: ```label.setPixmap(QPixmap(u":/icons/icon1.png"))```. I just tried to use the file option and it actually worked fine. Will there be any problems if I use this option when I try to transform the app in an .exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some months ignoring this particular problem from my project, I finally was able to solve it! What I did was to add the "icons" part to the prefix, and used pyside-rcc to convert the *.qrc* file into a *icons_rc.py*, following a tutorial from [PyQt's documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/qrcfiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Python Guys PYQT5 and PYQT6 and i know you will come here, Remember when compiling or when designing , you have to use the  MEI PASS to tell the executable to find icons in the temporary folder , not the exe location

```
executable_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
```